# Cast from 'String!' to unrelated type 'ViewController' always fails

Tags: swift, casting, segue

I'm getting an error this piece of code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "commentSegue" {
            let destVC = segue.destination as! CommentController

            **destVC.passedValue = valueToPass as? ViewController**
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to pass the data obviously in the function but I'm having a problem casting..I know there are lots of posts like this, I've probably looked at at least 13 by now, but I'm not very good at casting so I can't use other people's solutions for mine. Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you cast `valueToPass` as `ViewController` if it has to be a `String`? Moreover, don't use implicitly unwrapped optionals (`String!`) unless you have a good reason for doing so...

Comment: Can you show the declaration/definition of variable `passedValue`?

Comment: define a variable in the current class and assign value in the same. After that pass the value in the Prepare for Segue. There is no need to cast.

Comment: just assign the value to your property `destVC.passedValue = valueToPass` and you will be able to access that property in your destination view controller

Comment: That's what i tried originally but I get this error: "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'ViewController!'"

Comment: The compiler is telling you the problem. You have a String, and you're trying to assign it to a property of type ViewController. That's incorrect. You can't fix that by casting. You have to fix the problem, which is that `passedValue` is one type and `valueToPass` is a completely different thing. You're almost certainly just passing the wrong thing, or you're assigning to the wrong thing, and the compiler is telling you so.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are casting your `valueToPass` variable into `ViewController`?
If your `destinationVC.passedValue` is of type `String`, than you have to pass the value with type `String` only. Or you can cast into `String` in place of `ViewController` if you are not sure about type of variable to be passed.

Comment: In your code *** line, replace `as? ViewController `with type of your destinationVC variable

Comment: The type of destVC is 'CommentController', so I re-wrote the line like this: "            destVC.passedValue = valueToPass as! CommentController". However, I still end up with this error: Cannot assign value of type 'CommentController' to type 'ViewController!' and a warning that casting from string to unrelated type CommentController always fails...

Answer (score 0):

If `CommentController`'s `passedValue` property is of type string, then get rid of the cast to `ViewController`. I don't know why the `passedValue` property is of type `ViewController`, but if it is, you need to make sure that `valueToPass` is a view controller.

EDIT: It's better to optionally cast the `destVC`:

```
if let destVC = segue.destination as? CommentController {
    destVC.passedValue = valueToPass
}
```